# Hierarchy table query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a hierarchy table which looks like this:

```
id  child_id
1   2
2   3
2   4
3   5
3   6
3   7
4   8
4   9
4   10
```

How to write a query to get results in such format:

```
1
|_ 2
   |_ 3
   |  |_ 5
   |  |_ 6
   |  |_ 7
   |_ 4
      |_ 8
      |_ 9
      |_ 10
```

Comment: Can you show us your atempt? or explain a logic you have tried?

Comment: Do all your formatting stuff on client-side, not server-side.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu I am not in attempts phase yet as I just do not know how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I could do:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT id, CAST(NULL AS INT) as Parent, 1 AS Level, CAST(id AS varchar(255)) AS LevelChar FROM Hier WHERE id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT child_id AS id, hier.id AS Parent, Level + 1, CAST(LevelChar + '-' + CAST(child_id AS varchar(255)) AS varchar(255)) FROM Hier 
JOIN cte ON Hier.id = cte.id
)
SELECT ISNULL(REPLICATE(Space(2) + '|',Level-1),'') + CAST(id AS Varchar(255)) FROM cte
ORDER BY LevelChar, ID
```